# c++ defining one class in to another

Tags: c++, class

i've tried to solve my question about classes in c++.In order to prevent complicated issues , i'll write a sample code for my problem. Now  here is my problem.

```
class sample1
{
 public:
 //getter,setter,constructor and destructor functions
 private:
 string label; 

}

class sample2 // in sample2.h #include "sample1" is exist.
{
 public:
  //getter setter constructors and destructors.
  void addSample1(string label);
 private:
  vector<sample1*> sample1's;
}
```

Now, as you can see , I want to fill the vector in sample2 class with sample1 pointers. I tried to do this with following code but ,clearly vector could only stored one pointer since after exacution of addSample1 function, pointer lost.Here is my code which does not work.

```
void addSample1(string label)
{       
        sample1  samp1(label);
    sample1 * n_pointer=new samp1(label);
    n_pointer=&samp1;
    sample1's.push_back(n_pointer);
}
```

Is there anyone who can help me to fix my problem ? thanks in advance

Comment: You mean `vector<sample1*>`, right?

Comment: @tadman yea you're totally right, sorry for syntax errors, it is just an example for my problem

Comment: When posting code, please provide code that compiles.  It just makes things confusing when you have variables with apostrophe characters in them

Comment: @MooingDuck you're totally right, sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `addSample` should be just :

```
void addSample1(string label)
{       
    sample1s.push_back(new sample1(label));
}
```

And you will have to be careful and delete those pointers once you are done with them or store smart pointers in the vector instead.

What you are doing in `addSample` is really bad.

```
void addSample1(string label)
{       
    // creates a local sample1 object on the stack
    sample1  samp1(label);
    //creates a sample1 object on heap
    sample1 * n_pointer = new sample1(label);
    // overwrites the sample1 pointer with the address of the local object
    // this will leak memory as you have lost the pointer to the dynamically allocated object.
    n_pointer=&samp1;
    //pushes the pointer that points to the local object into the vector
    sample1s.push_back(n_pointer);

   // here the local object is destroyed so now the pointer in the vector 
   // points to deallocated space, accessing it will result in undefined behaviour
}
```

Comment: ,eyvallah hocam yanlız bir sey sormak ıstıyorum new sample1(label) pushlayarak tam olarak ne yapmıs oldum ? ılk defa goruyorum boyle bır seyı

Comment: `new sample1(label)` allocates and creates a new sample1 object. Putting it inside the push just adds that pointer at the end of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
void addSample1(string label)
{       
    sample1's.push_back(new sample1(label));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This ought to work:

```
void sample2::addSample1(string label)
{       
    sample1* n_pointer=new sample1(label);
    sample1s.push_back(n_pointer);
}
```

Rename your member variable:

```
private:
  vector<sample1*> sample1s;
```